# Time Machine backup of renamed computer fails

Tags: time-machine, backup, time-capsule

After getting a new MacBook Pro recently, I decided to reuse my old MacBook Pro as a home server. I reformatted the disk and reinstalled OS X, giving the computer a different hostname (let's call it *NewHostname*) in the process.

Now I want to back up the computer to the same Time Capsule I was using before. However, there is already an encrypted backup of the computer on that Time Capsule from when it was still called *OldHostname*. When I try to set up Time Machine, it returns an error message saying **"The disk "DiskName" already contains an encrypted backup for this computer."** This appears to be referring to the old sparsebundle image.

The only options Time Machine offers are to continue using the old sparsebundle or to erase it and start a new encrypted backup. Is there any way I could keep the old sparsebundle *and* start a new backup? And how does it even know that this encrypted file happens to correspond to this computer when the hostnames don't even match?

Note: I've already tried renaming the file in Finder from *OldHostname.sparsebundle* to *OldHostname-old.sparsebundle*, but that didn't work.

Comment: There is probably some hardware id's stored for the disk. Anyway you can try move it into a folder to get it out of the way and save it.

Comment: @Hoshts: I didn't expect that Time Machine would let me move the backup, so I didn't even think to try it. But I just did it now and it actually worked and solved the problem perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `tmutil inheritbackup`:

```
sudo tmutil inheritbackup /Volumes/Data/OldHostname.sparsebundle
```

From `man tmutil`:

```
inheritbackup {machine_directory | sparsebundle}
        Claim a machine directory or sparsebundle for use by the current
        machine. Requires root privileges.

        Machine directories and sparsebundles are owned by one computer
        at a time, and are tracked by unique identifiers rather than com-
        puter name, host name, or ethernet address. The inheritbackup
        verb reassigns the identity of the specified item, reconfiguring
        it so the current host recognizes it during backups. When inher-
        iting a sparsebundle, the machine directory within will also be
        claimed.

        Inheriting is typically only one step in the process of configur-
        ing a backup for use by a machine. You may also need to use
        setdestination, associatedisk, or both, depending on the situa-
        tion.

        One machine can own multiple machine directories and sparsebun-
        dles, but it is ill-advised for them to reside in the same place.
        In such a situation, which will be chosen during a backup is
        undefined. As a result, inheritbackup will attempt to detect pos-
        sible identity collisions before making changes.
```

See also http://pondini.org/TM/B6.html.

Comment: This actually seems to do the opposite of what I was looking for as it _assigns_ the backup to the computer, rather than _un-assigning_ it. Still, it's interesting that erasing the old volume in the OS X installer didn't change the UUID as they suggested it would.